# How do you compute a basic scoring system?

Tags: math, scoring

Example, we have a shooting balloon game where in balloon flies in the 'world' and an archer or shooter shoots the balloon before it flies out of the world. So, we have this stats:

```
Hits - balloons that were hit
Arrows - the number of bullets/arrows spent
Misses - is like Arrows - Hits
Escaped - balloons that player was not able to hit
```

I thought, accuracy is a good way to compute the score but when the player used 1 arrow and hits the balloon, his accuracy will be 100% (Hits/Arrows) so I need to include other statistics like missed or escaped in order to compute a better score. Maybe, we can even include the time spent.

I thought this is a common scenario but Google can't seem to give me any answer. Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: I think this really comes down to your imagination and game design. It's quite open? You can set the point values and penalty values as high or as low as you want, weighted however you want, within any range you want. You could start with a perfect scenario where one player that uses exactly the 1 arrow per balloon and hits all of them should earn a perfect score and work backwards, but again, it's really up to how you want to design it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing could be how many balloons were shot down, so something like

```
percentage_hit = hits/total_number_of_balloons
```

Afterwards, you can factor in accuracy, with

```
accuracy = hits/total_shots
```

So a basic scoring would be `accuracy*percentage_hit`. You might want to add a `*100` or so in there, so the score is a bigger number.

Another idea would be to assign every balloon hit a score, maybe based on how long it is on the field already. So if the players hits it very fast after it appears, it is worth more than when it is on the field longer.

Comment: It's weird that it's hits ^ 2 / total_balloons / total_shots

Comment: Just the idea of something being squared, then if hits is big, one will get and unusually high score. Just doesn't seem that fair.

Comment: I've never designed a great scoring system, maybe it's normal then.

Comment: Well, it's just math. Think about it; neither percentage_hit nor the accuracy can ever be more than 1, and as such, the product of both, even though it creates a square in the equation, can't either.

Comment: I've tested sample data to both formulas and seem ok (@Femaref and @Shane Hsu). I have to choose one so I'll just choose this one but both seems ok. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking the scoring this way.

Things to be encouraged:
Accuracy
Hits

Things to be discouraged:
Misses
Escaped
Arrows

Then you can figure out something from this.

I will suggest something like Accuracy * Hits - ( 1 - Accuracy ) * ( Misses + Escaped + Arrows )

And you should apply a modifier to these value to maybe normalize them, so no extreme scores will appear.